# Express: Redirect '/' to specific route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm asking for help after being unable to find a solution through other SO questions.

I'm doing some modular express app. This is the regarding part of `my server.js` file.

```
var app = express();
var login = require('./lib/login');
app.use(login);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

If I hit localhost:3000 It goes straight to public/index.html. But I want it to go to the `login` route. I've tried something like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){    
   res.redirect(__dirname + '/lib/login');
});
```

But it's not even being called since it always goes to index.html. Guess the line `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` is doing that from the get go. And Even if I comment that like for testing server's not redirecting to the route so I guess my code's not accurate.

I should add that inside the `login` route there's a `jade` template.

Any ideas?

**More Information**

Structure

```
/node_modules
/public
   /javascripts
   /stylesheets 
/lib
   /login
   /views
server.js
```

Inside the `public` folder there's the `index.html` file that's being called. It's there just for testing, it has nothing to do with the real jade files I want to render.

I first added the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` line so I can load my `javascripts` and my `stylesheets` in my `jade` templates with something like `script(src='/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.js')`. If I remove that original line from my `server.js` it DOES route `/` to `login` but then I can't seem to load those libraries inside `javascripts` and `stylesheets`, even if I change `script(src='/javascripts/...` to `script(src='/public/javascripts/...`

Comment: you realise __dirname means something like /computerroot/path/currentscriptpath/... right?

Comment: There is no `index.html` mentioned in your setup, where does it come from? You are running a node server, not apache, why would node redirect to some non-existent `index.html`? Are you sure you do not have apache on the same box, but on the default port and that your are not jus checking the default port in your browser?

Comment: @mpm I do, would you suggest that line to be changed?

Comment: Following @mpm: how about `res.redirect("/lib/login");`?

Comment: At some point I installed and used wamp for a bit, but then I got rid of it so there shouldnt be any apache left on the system... There's no redirection to index.html and that's what really sounds weird to me. I'm not that versed into `express` so I wasn't sure if by default it looks for `index.html` or smth. `res.redirect("/lib/login");` didn't work either. It goes straight to public/index.html